# printer not responding using CUPS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ubuntu-12.04, shared-printers

I have a windows server 2008 r2 set up and an Ubuntu 12.04. The FTP works and the printer I created in the server is accessible to the other client, a windows 7. I followed [this](http://gain4you.net/info/309/how-to-share-printer-over-ubuntu-network/) but no luck and of course I tried Googling and messing around, I created like 20 printers, none of them work, same issue. Any advice?

**Clarification:**

Printer is installed on the windows server. I just installed the *biopdf* on the server and a printer appeared. 
On Ubuntu I read I have to *add* a printer and *set* it to be the one on the server. So using *CUPS > Add Printer*. The issue is that on *Ubuntu* I can't print a test page, for it says *"printer not responding."* On the server it works fine. On another client, a *Win 7* it works fine (I didn't have to add anything on Win 7, after deploying from the server it just appeared).

Comment: But this guide how to print from Windows to Linux connected printer! Do I understand correctly - printer connected to the Windows server?

Comment: Where is the printer installed? (Ubuntu / Windows Server) Where is the printer not working? (Windows Server / Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most reliable way:

1. On Windows server connected to the printer install feature [LPR Port Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731857%28v=ws.11%29.aspx)
2. In the printer properties on the Sharing tab, check the box "Share this printer" and specify the name of the printer
3. Connect this printer to you Ubuntu host in CUPS as "LPD/LPR Host or Printer". Connection string will be `lpd://<windows_server_name_or_ip>/<printer_name_as_on_sharing_tab>`

Comment: Sir or madam, you saved the day. The way you told me, it did exactly what it should. I was messing with this for 3 days straight, you have my gratitude :D